# MySql dump and restore all dbs with saving type

Tags: mysql, bigint

How to dump and restore all dbs with saving type?

When I do it with `mysqldump` it dump `bigint` instead of `bigint(20)` as example.Look like it was working with mysql 5.7 but not work anymore in mysql 8. The problem with release or I do something wrong?

dump:

`mysqldump --user root --password --all-databases > all-databases.sql`

restore:

`mysql --user root --password mysql < all-databases.sql`

Comment: The datalength specifier is deprecated. And anycase it is ignored even when it is present.

Comment: Recommend with questions something more descriptive than "not work any more", like describing errors or behaviour.

Comment: My soft validate data type and length it is my internal error. It's not interested to anybody. The fact is the database doesn't have same types/length of data after dump/restore.  I think my question is understandable and informative enough.

Comment: It's ignored from MySql side but it maybe not ignored from a client side software.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.